# Which one is correct, "estuviera" o "estuvieran lloviendo todos los días"?

Tags: subjuntivo

Which one is correct, "Ojalá estuviera lloviendo todos los dias" or "Ojalá estuvieran lloviendo todos los días"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'llovieran' with N at the end but ONLY if after the verb 'llover' would be placed an object, e.g. lagrimas, estrellas... Ojalá llovieran tus lagrimas (better to say 'Ojalá NO llovieran tus lagrimas' si un hombre quiere evitar que su novia le dé calabazas :D).

For me it goes: Ojalá no lloviera todos los días.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada:) un placer

Answer (score 3):

The verb "llover" is usually impersonal and thus conjugated in the singular:

- Ojalá estuviera lloviendo todos los días.

However, the sentence above sounds a bit strange in the progressive. This would be more usual:

- Ojalá lloviera todos los días.

Comment: Thank you for your answer....How about "Ojala que las nubes llovieran."

Comment: Clouds don't rain...

Comment: Ok. Thank you for replying.

Comment: @Gustavson I think the first sentence sounds strange to you due to regional differences. In Colombia it sounds normal. A little more common is "Ojalá **que** estuviera lloviendo todos los dias"

Comment: I don't agree. A counterexample: "llovieron 100 milímetros en una hora"

Comment: @Leo You are right. We also have less scientific statements like "Llovieron sapos" and "LLovieron soretes de punta". I've edited my reply accordingly.